# IOException send pdf by Javamail via webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, ioexception

Guys I got a problem to send a PDF on java mail on webservice. When I try to run my class for test the email is send sucessful, but somehow when I try to send via webservice the same method can't find the File and shows `IOException (The path is not found)`. So how shall I describe the file path on the method to run it on web service?

Project Build and code.

[image]

Comment: Please paste your relevant code and error messages as *text*, not images!

Comment: Sorry I add as image to show the project structure because I think that is relevant in this problem.

Comment: Images can't be searched, we can't copy and paste the code to execute it... See [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you have use wrong path.

1. You should try use absolute path instead of relations path,
2. Use following code to debug:

   String tHomeArquiovo = ...

   System.out.println(new File(tHomeArquiovo).getAbsoluteFile());